# timeDate mangles data.frame names

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> data.frame(a=2)
  a
1 2
```

Here `a` is correctly taken as the column name of the data frame. But if I try
to put a `timeDate` object (from the `timeDate` package):

```
> library(timeDate)
> data.frame(a=timeDate("2016-02-05 08:20:00"))
           GMT.x..i..
1 2016-02-05 08:20:00
```

You see that the column name is nothing like I specified.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

I realize I can just set the `names` attribute, but this error-prone, and I'd rather use the assignment syntax.

Comment: Why can't you just use `as.POSIXct("2016-02-05 08:20:00")`?

Comment: Because I find useful the functionality provided by that package.

Comment: What do you have to wrap a data frame around `a`?

Comment: I assume you meant "why"? Because in my real example, a data frame contains other data besides timeDate.

Comment: You could do `data.frame(a = attr(timeDate("2016-02-05 08:20:00"), "Data"))` but I'm not sure if this will keep all the features you need.

Comment: Try `data.frame(a=timeDate("2016-02-05 08:20:00")@Data)`

Comment: Maybe it's better to wrap it into a list instead of a data frame...